# Inputs order in the form with Booststrap

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem  with setting right order of inputs in the form on the mobile view using Bootstrap. I already asked similar question, and got some tips and have been told is easy. I tried many things and i just don't know how to get required result.

Take a look at the jsfiddle please.

https://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/y79LwL9x/8/

I want input with placeholder (17 - Error Text Area) to be on the top of the (20 - Button).

Visual graph:

[image]

And HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="1" class="form-control" />
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="2" class="form-control" />
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="3" class="form-control" />
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="4" class="form-control" />
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="5" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="6" class="form-control" />
                <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="7" class="form-control" />
                <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="8" class="form-control" />
                <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="9" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="10" class="form-control" />
                <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="11" class="form-control" />
                <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="12" class="form-control" />
                <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="13" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="14" class="form-control" />
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="15" class="form-control" />
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="16" class="form-control" />
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="17 - Error Text Area" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="18" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="19" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="20 - Button" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...got some tips and have been told is easy.

I'm with you, it wasn't that easy. If it was that easy you would've gotten an answer that works.

### SOLUTION

You can use flexbox on inputs 17 to 20 and use the flexbox property `order`.

```
  .flex { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
  .flex1 { order:3; }
  .flex2 { order:1; }
  .flex3 { order:2; }
  .flex4 { order:4; }
  @media screen and (min-width:1000px) {
    .flex { display: inline; }
  }
```

These rulesets basically are saying:

> The 4 designated flex items (children of a flex container, i.e. .flex1, .flex2, .flex3, .flex4) will be reordered as:
>
> - 3rd is now 1st,
> - 1st is now 2nd,
> - and 2nd is now 3rd
>
> When the viewport is wider than 1000px, the flex container (i.e. .flex) will be a harmless inline element.

In order to make the styles work without disrupting the layout, there had to be some changes to the HTML:

- Wrapped `<span class='flex'>` around inputs 17 to 20.
- Assigned classes `.flex1, .flex2, .flex3, .flex4` to inputs 17 to 20.
- The last 3 divs classes changed from `.col-md-4` to `.col-md-3`.
- Removed `.col-md-9` and `.row` that was wrapped around inputs 18 to 20.
- Moved input 17 inside `.flex` and wrapped a `<div class='col-md-3'>` around it.

[<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/PrubtjEWQfisoo3SEXIj/)

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    .flex {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .flex1 {
      order: 3;
    }
    .flex2 {
      order: 1;
    }
    .flex3 {
      order: 2;
    }
    .flex4 {
      order: 4;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
      .flex {
        display: inline;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="1" class="form-control" />
      <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="2" class="form-control" />
      <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="3" class="form-control" />
      <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="4" class="form-control" />
      <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="5" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="6" class="form-control" />
          <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="7" class="form-control" />
          <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="8" class="form-control" />
          <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="9" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="10" class="form-control" />
          <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="11" class="form-control" />
          <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="12" class="form-control" />
          <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="13" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="14" class="form-control" />
      <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="15" class="form-control" />
      <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="16" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <span class='flex'>
    <div class="col-md-3 flex1">
      <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="17 - Error Text Area" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 flex2">
      <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="18" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 flex3">
      <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="19" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 flex4">
      <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="20 - Button" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</span>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, it was very frustrating. Thanks for clear explenation too. It is a very interesting solution.

Comment: You're very welcome, it's easier without Bootstrap unless you are good at it. I'm not so this was good practice.